# Excel VBA refer to Table name insert data after last row

Tags: excel, vba, insert, find

I am trying to find a simple way to refer to the NAME of a formatted table and insert data after the last row of the table I am referring to

Currently I am referring to a column - but I want to make it with the name of the table

```
Sub lastrow()
    Dim Last1 As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
        Last1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add a new row to a table/listobject

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").listobjects("tableNameHere").ListRows.Add().Range

'work with rng, which is the newly-added row
```

Comment: i get subscript out of range :(

Comment: Do you have a Sheet2 and a table named whatever you put in place of "tableNameHere" ?

Comment: yes - i even tried to rename the sheet to "xxx" and table to "yyy" so i make sure i am not making mistake

Comment: It works for me (though I'd forgotten to add the `.Range` after `.Add()`)   Maybe an issue with ThisWorkbook vs. ActiveWorkbook ?  Try breaking that line up: first set a worksheet variable to sheet2 and then set the listobject from that - that will tell you what's not being found.